# Deploy multiple projects at a time in one click using Octopus

Tags: deployment, devops, cicd, octopus-deploy, octopus

We have 50+ small projects running on different servers. Projects are the combination of microservices, windows applications, angular micro frontend applications, and SQL database projects. All these projects are deployed using Octopus in a CICD manner.
We want to move all of the projects from the old server to the new server. To deploy all of the projects on new servers we need to click on the deploy button for each 50+ project. Can we deploy all the projects in one click using the octopus?

Trying to deploy different applications through the octopus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Deploy a Release](https://octopus.com/docs/projects/coordinating-multiple-projects/deploy-release-step) to deploy a release for a different project.

Put one step for each project into a single parent project and use that to deploy all your child projects.